# MQL create new candles

Tags: mql4

the bid price in my MT4 are roughly 1 pip below what my broker's trade prices are.  The reason is that the price server serving the charts has a spread of 2.5 pips where my broker is much narrower in spreads (0.2 pips).

I need to redraw the candles on the fact that everything should be about 1 pip higher than what it is being drawn.

I've studied histogram drawing but it doesn't help me with the drawing of the entire candle.

Is it possible to redraw the candle in its entirety about 1 pip higher than what the price server is giving me?

If the candles could be drawn on the halfway mark between bid and ask, it would work close on correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Add all candles in array (`CopyRates` or loop over them from `Bars`-1 to 0) then create a new symbol as it is shown in PeriodConverter and write all candles from 0 to last to have an offline chart, include your manipulations with price here. Then update the chart if you need to have live chart, or resave under existing name in order to backtest(do not forget to disconnect first, otherwise mt4 will upload quotes from the server and overwrite over your file)